# WSO2 ESB : UDP to HTTP transform

Tags: udp, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to convert UDP messages to HTTP in a high performance manner. So I thought about doing it with WSO2 ESB. 
So I tried sample tutorial https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26838866
And sample works well.

So then I tried to call to the ESB proxy with a UDP message generation tool (packetsender). But there I can't send just a string value as the UDP message and I have to send full soap message with each UDP message. i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <m0:placeOrder xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
        <m0:order>
            <m0:symbol>IBM</m0:symbol>
        </m0:order>
    </m0:placeOrder>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So is it possible to all this endpoint with UDP message that only have string (without sending whole SOAP information)? May be there we might need to change the following proxy service of ESB,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="UDPProxy"
       transports="udp"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
      </inSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:9764"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.udp.port">9998</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.udp.contentType">text/xml</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your proxy def and adapt content type to your need :

```
<parameter name="transport.udp.contentType">text/plain</parameter>
```

Comment: Thanks it is working now. I wonder where the applicable values for this property (transport.udp.contentType) is documented on wso2 docs. But I couldn't find it.

Comment: Have a look in repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml and search for declared messageBuilders. Can't help you for the documentation...